# Prove this expectation of Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Prove $E[(\Delta B_j)^4]=3(\Delta t_j)^2$ where the Delta stands for the change of something i.e $B_j-B_{j-1}=\Delta B_j$ and the $B_j$ stand for the standard Brownian motion

I won't show my step here since i know it is a few step computation, i think my mistake on conceptual got me wrong from start

Here is the second degree example with answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308705/show-a-lemma-of-brownian-motion-is-valid

The difficulty is that i can't just use the second degree example to convert it into four degree solution...

Comment: Why it is off topic?

Comment: @avid19 - This is a few step problem, however it seems to me that the internet only provide the second power example and i don't think i am close to the real concept yet.

Comment: "The change of something?" Can you be a bit more specific??

Comment: "Why it is off topic?" Because *This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.*

Comment: @Victor : They shouldn't be calling it off topic.  Instead they should say what the actual objection to the question is.  A lot of people here frown on phrasing a question in a style appropriate to assigning homework. That can make people suspect that the question was merely copied by someone who doesn't understand what it says.  Explaining what difficulties you had could resolve the problem. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Victor : Lots of people here simply down-vote and vote to close questions that have the problem identified in my earlier comment, without posting an explanation like the one in my comment.  They ought to post that explanation.

Comment: @MichaelHardy On the other hand, one could expect that a user active on the site for nearly 4 years with more than 250 questions under their belt could have become even moderately interested in the basics of the functioning of the site, don't you think? Or, all this is just a bad play, where some users deliberately mimic surprise, with the goal to continue to knowingly post questions whose format explicitely contradicts (good sense and) the rules of the site. In the end, who **ought** what, one wonders.

Comment: @Did You shouldn't pick on people like that

Comment: Like what? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did - You should try to focusing on other person instead of just me.

Comment: Pffff... $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely the fact that if $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ then $\operatorname{E}(X^4)=3\sigma^4$.  If $Z=X/\sigma\sim N(0,1)$ then clearly $\operatorname{E}(Z^4)=\operatorname{E}(X^4)/\sigma^4$, so it is enough to prove $\operatorname{E}(Z^4)=3$.
$$
\operatorname{E}(Z^4)=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^4 e^{-z^2/2}\,dz.
$$
Let $u=z^2/2$ so that $du = z\ dz$.  Then we have
$$
2\cdot\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty (2u)^{3/2} e^{-u}\,du=2\cdot\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot2\sqrt2\cdot \Gamma(5/2) = 2\cdot\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot\frac32\cdot\frac12\cdot\Gamma(1/2) 
$$
$$
=2\cdot\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot 2\sqrt2 \cdot\frac32\cdot\frac22\cdot\sqrt\pi = 3.
$$